# installing icons on gwsl

Tags: gnome, nautilus, icons, themes, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Ubuntu wsl2, Windows subsystem for Linux. GWSL is an awesome tool to run GUI apps on it. Going to `GWSL Distro Tools > GTK Themes`, allows you to use custom themes.

The problem is that how can I change the icons. For example in Nautilus the theme doesn't look good with the default icons & I have already installed an icon in both `/usr/share/icons` & `~/.icons`.

I have tried using `gnome-tweaks`, but it doesn't even recognize the icons. Also even thought I have switched the theme, it displays it as the default one in `gnome-tweaks`.

Comment: And just a heads-up that you can now use WSLg on Windows 10 as well.  You may still prefer GWSL, but just putting out there as an additional option -- Not that I think the use of GWSL or WSLg will change the answer here ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, you have to save a back up of `usr/share/Adwaita` and then put everything in your icons theme into `usr/share/Adwaita` except the `index` file.

This method, at least worked for `candy-icons`.